# can not filter pagination on table filter with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/shaliapin777/3knda25n/9/

I`m filtering table data with pagination
also I need to filter data with filter-inputs

it is filtering but pagination not working

I do not understand how to do so, that when filtering from upside inputs pagination must filter too and if element is faded out, it must not count this tr...

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need select this rows from mysql with mysql LIKE and only after that you need to render pagination...

I do not know but if is best way
I think it is...

may be someone can give you other more comfortable way to do this...